# MSVC cl.exe trying to use C++ header paradigm (definition vs declaration)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cl

I'm trying to implement a library that uses the rather popular C++ header paradigm (separating definition and declaration in a .h / .hpp and a .cpp file).
I'm using the MSVC cl.exe compiler to target the Windows operating system.

I explicitly use the `#include` directive targeting the header file `abc.hpp` where the definition is expressed. I expect the compiler to automatically look for the corresponding `abc.cpp` file and redirect calls to `abc.hpp::abc()` towards `abc.cpp::abc()`.

(I know I could directly `#include "abc.cpp"` in the example but remember I'm trying to solve a bigger problem that is include an entire library from it's header files.)

(I also tried to use the `/I` compiler option but after both testing and reading the documentation it's not of much use.)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/i-additional-include-directories

I described the test I run bellow and the compiler error I get:

```
######## main.cpp ######## 
#include <stdio.h> // printf_s
#include "abc.hpp"
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    abc();
    return(0);
}

######## abc.hpp ######## 
void abc();

######## abc.cpp ######## 
#include "abc.hpp"

void abc() {
    printf("ABC!\n");
}

######## command line ########
> cl main.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.X for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

main.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.X
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:main.exe
main.obj
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl abc(void)" (?abc@@YAXXZ) referenced in function main
main.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Is my expectation about the compiler automatically remapping `abc.hpp::abc()` towards `abc.cpp::abc()` off the mark?
Am I forced to have the `.cpp` code be compiler as a separate `.lib` to be able to `/link /LIBPATH:` it to the compiler?

I'd be pleased to hear your insight about this matter.

Comment: You need to compile both `main.cpp` and `abc.cpp` and then link them together to make the final executable.  Please explain why you want to use the command line rather than the IDE?  Tempted to flag as a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: try ```cl main.cpp abc.cpp```.. it will link two cpp into one exe.

Comment: Are you telling me to make a unity build of both main.cpp and abc.cpp? If so I would have to make an entire unity build for the whole library. Which is doable but I expected libraries to be easier to use. Also not many people uses unity build so I am skeptical as of people using that strategy in order to use this archetype of library.
(I'm trying to use the `glslang` library.)

> Why use the command line rather than the IDE?
Because all I want to is compile. I don't need visual studio to add hidden files and folder to my project.

Comment: (1) No one is suggesting a Unity Build.  (2) where does a library come into this (not in the question). (3) you seem to mixing up basic compile, link terminology.

Comment: @PeterLee `cl main.cpp abc.cpp` doesn't quite seem to be the solution here. ```main.cpp
main.cpp(6): error C3861: 'abc': identifier not found
abc.cpp
abc.cpp(5): error C3861: 'printf': identifier not found
Generating Code...```
Also I don't expect myself to write the path of every single `.cpp` file this library contains within this command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @RichardCritten then I did not understand what you meant by compiling both `.cpp` file then linking them together. Would you mind describing the process by an example?

Comment: @RichardCritten Please read the first line of the question again you might have missed it.

Comment: @RichardCritten Would you mind pointing out "basic compile, link terminology" I "seem to mix[...] up"?

Comment: @Mendear Such feature is not supported by MSVC.. MSVC expect you to write every signle cpp path within command line.. That is why peoples use IDE, Makefile, etc

Comment: "I expect the compiler to automatically look for the corresponding abc.cpp file" thats not how it works

Comment: Thank you @formerlyknownas_463035818 that answer one of the question, would you mind answering the second question? "Am I forced to have the .cpp code be compiler as a separate .lib to be able to /link /LIBPATH: it to the compiler?"

Comment: you need to include, `<stdio.h>` in `abc.h` or `abc.cpp` then I would expect `cl main.cpp abc.cpp` to work. The error you quote in a comment is due to `printf` not `abc`

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 You are absolutely right. I assume main.cpp and abc.cpp are compiled independently before being linked together, which would explains why you need to include it for each file.
In the case I want to use a library that contains a lot of those kind of `.cpp` files including `.h` and `.hpp` files I need to list those `.cpp` after the `cl` call? Or is there a more efficient option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a ... let's say more reasonable opinion on how C++ compile and linking should work. But the truth is that the C++ include compile and link model is ancient and seems alien to any modern modular builds in modern languages. However it is so encarved into C++, that is the way it goes with C++ and that was the way since the beginning. Things are about to change (slowly) with modules being introduced into the standard in C++20 (really a great and arduous achievement considering C++'s legacy and backwards-compatibility).

---

So the classical way is this: You include headers that contain the declaration you need. `#include` is a preprocessor directive and it is more-or-less just a dumb copy-paste of the contents of the header. This lets you compile each "compilation unit" individually. Then you link all of the compilation units into your final binary (bee it a library or an executable).

Let's say you have a `foo.cpp` with the definition of the function `foo`.

`foo.cpp`

```
int foo(int a)
{
     return a * a;
}
```

If you need to call `foo` from another compilation unit you first need to make the declaration of `foo` visible in that compilation unit. You can do that easily just by writing the declaration:

`bar.cpp`

```
int foo(int);

void bar()
{
    int r = foo(24);
}
```

Before using `foo` the compiler need to know what `foo` is. Aka it needs to know it is a function taking an int parameter and returning an int. That is what I did in the example above when I wrote `int foo(int)`. Hower you shouldn't write each declaration. You can write the declaration of `foo` once in `foo.hpp` and then include that header:

`foo.hpp`

```
#pragma once // or standard-compliant guard

int foo(int);
```

`bar.cpp`

```
#include "foo.hpp"

void bar()
{
    int r = foo(24);
}
```

The preprocessor wil textually replace `#include "foo.hpp"` with the contents of the file before feeding it to the compiler.

Now you can compile `bar.cpp` into an object file. The compiler just writes a call to a symbol `foo` known to name a function taking an int parameter and returning an int. However the definition of `foo` is not visible. Aka. the compiler doesn't have the "source code" of `foo`.

So the next step is to link together all the compilation units.

You can do the compilation and linking in two separate stages (I use `g++` in the examples because I am more familiar with the parameters, but the principles are the same for cl.exe):

```sh
# compile each compilation unit
g++ bar.cpp -o bar.o
g++ foo.cpp -o foo.o

# link all into the final executable
g++ bar.o foo.o -o my_executable
```

Or you can do it all in one go:

```sh
g++ foo.cpp bar.cpp -o my_executable
```

Because `cl.exe` (and `clang` and `gcc`) is neither the compiler nor the linker. It's a front end that calls the preprocessor, compiler and/or linker on your behalf.

---

You need to know these details to understand what is happening under the hood so you can solve issues when they appear, but you shouldn't manually invoke the compiler. Use a build system that will take care of all this for you. Let VS do this for you or use make / cmake.

Comment: Hello @bolov ! I now understand better the intrinsic of the problem and am now better armed for solving future instances of that same problem archetype. Your explanation, your time and your energy is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: For now I was using my own `.bat` file to describe my compilation needs. Up until now is was enough for my own code and the single file libraries I was using. The need for a tool like make / cmake now arises from the desire to use some third party libraries. It seems that I can't put aside this complexity anymore. I'll give a go at cmake up until I get a better understanding of what I'm working with, glslang was made with make / cmake in mind anyway. Again, thank you for your insight.

Comment: @Mendear you are welcome. Consider upvoting if it helped you and accepting an answer.

Comment: I did !
However : "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."